# Pandas - How can I set rules for selecting which duplicates to drop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with values in the column and in the index datetime objects.
What I want to do is drop the values that have the same index (date&time), but I want to make a rule like:

---

I have two values for the same datetime, so I want to pick the one closer to number X. That number could be for example the mean value of the whole dataset.

---

The dataset looks like this (I did reset the index when trying to make it happen because I got an error for having multiple indices):

```
         index                  kwh
16391   2014-10-26 03:14:59     0.0514139
16392   2014-10-26 03:29:59     0.0323344
16393   2014-10-26 03:29:59     12.3
16394   2014-10-26 03:44:59     0.0595618
16395   2014-10-26 03:59:59     0.0338677
```

if X (for example mean value) is 0.05 then what I want to get back is

```
16391   2014-10-26 03:14:59     0.0514139
16392   2014-10-26 03:29:59     0.0323344
16393   2014-10-26 03:44:59     0.0595618
16394   2014-10-26 03:59:59     0.0338677
```

I have tried using groupby and apply in several different ways but I cant get it to work.
Any help please?

Comment: Please post raw input data and a representative df and the desired output

Comment: ok, I just updated it

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `dist` column to the DataFrame which measures the absolute distance
between `kwh` and `X`:

```
X = df['kwh'].mean()
df['dist'] = (df['kwh'] - X).abs()
```

then you can groupby `index` and find the unique integer indices with the minimum `dist` for each group:

```
idx = df.groupby(['index'])['dist'].transform(lambda x: x == x.min()).astype(bool)
```

Then you can select those rows using `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[idx]
```

---

If `data` contains (note the duplicate values of `kwh` for the same `index`):

```
         index                  kwh
16391   2014-10-26 03:14:59     0.0514139
16392   2014-10-26 03:29:59     0.0323344
16392   2014-10-26 03:29:59     0.0323344
16393   2014-10-26 03:29:59     12.3
16394   2014-10-26 03:44:59     0.0595618
16395   2014-10-26 03:59:59     0.0338677
```

then

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')
print(df)
X = df['kwh'].mean()
df['dist'] = (df['kwh'] - X).abs()
idx = df.groupby(['index'])['dist'].transform(lambda x: x == x.min()).astype(bool)
print(df.loc[idx])
```

yields

```
                     index       kwh      dist
16391  2014-10-26 03:14:59  0.051414  2.033505
16392  2014-10-26 03:29:59  0.032334  2.052584
16392  2014-10-26 03:29:59  0.032334  2.052584
16394  2014-10-26 03:44:59  0.059562  2.025357
16395  2014-10-26 03:59:59  0.033868  2.051051
```

Note that by using `transform` here, we get a boolean mask which allows us to select *all rows* -- including those with duplicate values of `kwh` -- which have the minimum distance from `X`.

---

You could use `del df['dist']` to drop the dist column when you no longer need it.

Comment: yes i already thought it could be done with something like that, or maybe if I took all duplicate values (I dont need to take the whole dataset, it will be much quicker I guess). 
Also, how can I take all duplicate values, including the first ones? (if I have 2 same values .duplicated will return just the second value.)
Though I was wondering if you could do it immediately using lambda, apply and groupby.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are saying. Can you create a sample DataFrame with the desired output?

Comment: I thought of a way to make it happen, I assume it will be faster, but now I have a different problem.
What I am now trying to do and I cannot, is to get all duplicate values by index. I would use df.duplicated(subset=df.index) , but this skips the first time that the specific index occures.
For example if I have df:

>                     index       kwh
>2014-10-26 03:14:59  0.051414
>2014-10-26 03:14:59  0.624514
>2014-10-26 03:29:59  0.032334

df.duplicated will return only the 0.624514 value, I need both 0.624514 and 0.051414
I am sorry I am trying to insert code into comments I cant do it

Comment: It's better to edit your original Q and put the code and question there.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a way to retain rows with duplicate values of `kwh`.